# ¿Cómo instalar librerías en python desde la terminal de python 3.6?

Tags: python, python-3.x, src

[image: Error de ejecución por ausencia de librerías.]

Estoy intentando crear mi primer Instabot pero no puedo encontrar las librerías necesarias para dicha operación. Entro a la terminal de python para instalar los módulos necesarios pero no he podido encontrar ni conozco cómo descargar las librerías como muestro en la imagen.

Si puedes ayudarme agradecería un paso a paso o una forma clara de hacerlo.

Comment: debes instalarlo desde el sistema operativo, usando el comando `pip install instabot`

Comment: Como comenta Emanuel la instalación la puedes hacer desde pip pero esto **se hace desde la terminal/CMD, no desde el intérprete Python**, p.e: `python -3 -m pip install instabot` No obstante según el código que muestras no estas intentando usar el modulo instalado, sino que te descargas el repositorio de GitHub directamente e importas desde el directorio `src` directamente. Tienes dos videotutoriales al final del repo: https://github.com/instabot-py/instabot.py mostrando esto. Si instalas via pip los imports deben cambiar. Un saludo.

Comment: si usas sistemas operativos GNU/linux denes hacer `python3 -m pip install instabot`

Comment: Como lo estas creando si no tienes la libreria? diga descarge y la opcion para hacerlo es con `pip install -r requeriments.txt` que supongo que vino con el proyecto descargado

Comment: Debes agregar un ejemplo mínimo que pueda reproducir notablemente el error que estas obteniendo, sabiendo esto es posible revisar foros online que contengan información sobre la aserción

Answer (score 0):

Primero, te recomiendo crear una entorno virtual para realizar estos "experimentos", puesto que esto te facilitará a futuro eliminar/agregar librerias y que no queden sobre otras.

Para instalarlo se requiere hacer lo siguiente (para la versión de Python que estás trabajando):

```
virtualenv -p python3 envname
```

Luego, para llamar el entorno virtual tienes que colocar lo siguiente:

```
source ../envname/bin/activate
```

Para salir, sólo tienes que llamar deactivate en tu consola.

Finalmente, para poder instalar todas las librerias que requieres para tu script, te recomiendo leer bien el readme de la aplicación e instalar sólo lo que requieres y sus versiones respectivas. Con pip debería bastarte para instalar cada una de ellas.

Recuerda iniciar tu entorno virtual en la consola, luego con pip instalar cada una de las librerias y luego podrás jugar con instabot a tu gusto.